# Autodesk-model-derivative: Creating a bucket: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am trying to create a bucket as described in [Create an App-Managed Bucket and Upload a File](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/app-managed-bucket/). When I use cURL in a command-box, it works good:

```
curl
 -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets"
 -X "POST"
 -H "Content-Type: application/json"
 -H "Authorization: Bearer ObfuscatedBucketCreateToken"
 -d "{"""bucketKey""":"""itx5""", """policyKey""":"""transient"""}"
```

Now I try to do the same with C# / visual studio:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets");
    request.Method = "POST";

    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(@"{""bucketKey"":""Itx7"", ""policyKey"":""transient""}");

    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.ContentType = @"application/json";
    request.Headers.Add(@"Authorization: Bearer ObfuscatedBucketCreateToken");

    using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }

    using (HttpWebResponse webRresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        long length = webRresponse.ContentLength;
        using (Stream stream = webRresponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // do your thing
        }
    }
```

On the request.getResponse() I get the exception "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request".

I a similar way, I am able to get OAth-tokens, but somehow, when I try to create a bucket, it always returns this exception.

Why do I get this exception? Is there a way to investigate why I get this exception?

Answer (score 2):

It looks you specified the bucket name with upper case when testing in C#. 
    ""Itx7""
API help says:

```
    HTTP / 1.1 **400** Bad Request
     ......

   {
    **"reason":"Valid field 'bucketKey' must be of the form  [-_.a-z0-9]    
    {3,128}"** 
   }
```

We have a blog on bucket. Most of the descriptions are still applied to new version:

http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/01/buckets-in-autodesk-view-and-data-api.html

Hope these are helpful.

Regards,

Xiaodong Liang 
  Forge Adovater
  Developer Technical Services
  Autodesk